# Binding to ColumnDefinition.ActualWidth has no effect

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, grid

I'm trying to bind to the ActualWidth of a column but the binding doesn't seem to work. In the following example the TextBlock with the binding is always 0 yet the TextBlock updated via code reports the correct number. What's happening?

XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" Name="MainColumn" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="From Binding:" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=MainColumn, Path=ActualWidth}" />
        <TextBlock Text="From Code:" />
        <TextBlock Text="" Name="WidthFromCodeTextBlock" />
    </StackPanel>
    <GridSplitter HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="5" DragDelta="GridSplitter_DragDelta" />
</Grid>
```

Code:

```
private void GridSplitter_DragDelta(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DragDeltaEventArgs e)
{
    WidthFromCodeTextBlock.Text = MainColumn.ActualWidth.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a dependency property, hence no binding updates.

*(Also, why do you have columns if you don't [**use them**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.column.aspx)?)*

Comment: How can I accomplish the binding to ActualWidth then? btw, this is just an example that shows my problem so there's no need to *use* the columns.

Comment: @Manuel: You can place some dummy object in the column and bind the ActualWidth of that.